# Unable to launch the URL on web in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to launch a URL on the web platform and that works if I use this URL: `https://flutter.dev`, but when I use this URL: `https://www.google.com`, it doesn't work and shows this `www.google.com refused to connect.`

This is the code I am using:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;
import 'platform_view_registry.dart' if(kIsWeb) 'platform_view_registry.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWebApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWebApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWebApp> createState() => _MyWebAppState();
}

class _MyWebAppState extends State<MyWebApp> {
final url = "https://www.google.com";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      final html.IFrameElement iFrameElement = html.IFrameElement()
        ..src = url
        ..style.border = 'none'
        ..style.width = '100%'
        ..style.height = '100%';

      platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
        'webview',
            (int viewId) => iFrameElement,
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Web Application"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                webSpecificFunction(context);
                //html.window.open(url, 'Google Authentication', 'popup');
              },
              child: const Text("Login")),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void webSpecificFunction(BuildContext context) {
    print("Executing the web specific function");
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text("Login"),
          content: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: 800,
            child: HtmlElementView(
              viewType: 'webview',
              key: UniqueKey(),
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(onPressed: (){
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            }, child: const Text("Close"))
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me figure out the problem or how to launch a URL on the same page on the web platform?